# Viewport only showing objects in camera shot

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I was just experimenting with the new smoke simulation stuff and something's happened. It seems that blender is only rendering things that are in the camera's view when in Solid Mode. What's even weirder is that it's seems to be from a location that the camera isn't in.

Here's an example of my scene which has a plane and an adaptive smoke domain in the middle. You can see that it's showing slices based on the origin point towards the lower right.
[image: Example in Solid Mode]

It's also displaying very strange in Material Mode as well (The plane just has a basic grey material but half of it ghosts as I move the camera around)

[image: Weird ghosting example]

Have I pressed something without realising it or is this actually a bug? It's hard to tell since blender has crashed so many times while trying to make an explosion.

Comment: This is a clipping region. Use Alt+B. Have a look at the menu "View/View Regions".

Comment: This fixed it, shouldn't you have posted as an answer?

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for before I posted but didn't know what to search. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (or the corresponding menu *'View/View Regions'*) can be used to define (or remove) a 3D clipping region.

[image: er]