# Strange Perspective and Viewport Issue

Tags: 3d-view, camera, scene

I have been having an issue with my viewport that I can't seem to figure out. The mesh that I have for my ground plane has strange clipping and perspective issues in wireframe mode and object mode. When I am in render view or lookdev mode the plane appears as normal.

[image]

[image]

I have tried deleting the ground plane and the camera. When I delete the camera the 'shadow' of the camera position remains. When I try to add a new plane I still have the same perspective and clipping issue. It seems like I have somehow locked the camera in this position, but I am still able to move the camera around and into new positions, but there is strange clipping on them within this new perspective I somehow manage to create.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what I managed to do here? I have been trying to figure it out for 2 hours...

Many thanks,
Collin

Comment: Have a look to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167746/viewport-only-showing-objects-in-camera-shot/167749#167749